# Spring Integration : Namespace change before sending request to ESB or other webservices

Tags: spring

I am using spring integration for developing webservices as project requirement and
I am looking some way to modify the namespace when sending the request to other interface let's say Mule ESB or other webservice. As per of project need, I need to have namespace for my webservice internally as let's say "xmlns:mod="http://www.xyx.com/pojo" while the interface(like Mule ESB) uses "xmlns:mod="http://www.xyx.com/model" namespace. so before sending the request to Mule ESB, I need to modify namespace for the request payload so that ESB can map the object elements and again, when receive the response from Mule ESB interface, I need to again modify the namespace as needed for mapping to my project interface.

Please let me know if this is feasible to do this and if yes then how could I achieve this in spring integration.

Thanks,
Vinay Agrawal

I tried to do the same as below but getting error IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Please see the below configuration done to achieve this purpose:

```
<int:gateway id="test1SoapESBGateway" service-interface="com.test1.test2.testServiceSoap">
    <int:method name="testResponse" request-channel="test1ESBRequestChannel" request-timeout="${soap.requestTimeout}" reply-timeout="${soap.replyTimeout}" />
</int:gateway>

<int-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="marshaller" input-channel="test1ESBRequestChannel" output-channel="test2ESBResponseChannel"></int-xml:marshalling-transformer>

<int:transformer input-channel="test2ESBResponseChannel" output-channel="test2ESBTransformedResponseChannel" ref="changeNamespaceTransformerBean"
    method="transformNamespace"></int:transformer>

<bean id="changeNamespaceTransformerBean" class="com.test1.test2.ChangeNamespaceTransformerImpl"></bean>

<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="ws-test1SoapESB-gateway" request-channel="test2ESBTransformedResponseChannel" uri="${soap.test1URI}">
</int-ws:outbound-gateway>

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
<property name="contextPaths">
    <list>
        <value>com.test1.test2.model</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

as above, I am getting the java object payload from testServiceSoap interface method testResponse and then trying to process this payload using int-xml:marshalling-transformer as per of your previous suggestion and then passing this into int:transformer where I want to change my soap namespace from http://www.test1.com/test2 to something like http://www.test4.com/test3 but I am getting the below exception when trying to deploy the war file into the server:

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException. Please see server.log for more details.

ChangeNamespaceTransformerImpl definition is as below:

ublic class ChangeNamespaceTransformerImpl {

```
public ChangeNamespaceTransformerImpl() {
}

public ChangeNamespaceTransformerImpl(DOMSource payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
}


public DOMSource transformNamespace(DOMSource payload) 
        {
    DOMSource result = payload;
    return result;
    }
```

Please let me know if I am missing something. I was considering that after applying int-xml:marshalling-transformer and then int:transformer, I should be able to do changes in my bean ChangeNamespaceTransformerImpl defined in int:transformer and there I should have the way to replace the namespace since payload will be in xml format.

Please provide your input/suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the XML of SOAP request/response is the same.

So you can use `<int-xml:marshaller-transformer>` for your POJO before `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` and some simple `replace-string` `<int:transformer>`.

And the same vise versa after receiving response.

Let me know, if you need more info.

**UPDATE**

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException.

Looks like you have a mix of Spring Integration jar versions: e.g. `spring-integration-core` is of `4.0`, but `spring-integration-xml` is of some older version.

Since Spring Integration 4.0 `MessagingException` has been moved to the Spring Framewrok 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for your input Artem. I appreciate your speedy reply. Again I am still facing some issue after following your suggestion. So I have updated my Question with my configuration and the error I am getting. Please give your valuable suggestion on this.

Comment: Added an edit to my answer regarding your last exception

Comment: Thanks Artem. this is working as per of your suggestion, I was using spring-integration-xml 3.00 version and now changed to 4.0.0.RELEASE version. Thank you very much for your great support.